# How to use threading/multiprocessing to prevent program hanging?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pyside

I am a bit confused with multiprocessing. I have a video processing script which can be run from the command line or launched from a PySide application using a subprocess call. The script seems to run fine from the command line and basically initializes a pool of workers which each process a separate video file.

When I run the program however the OS tells me my program is not responding. I would like to make use of all the cores on my system for multiprocessing but I would also like to prevent this annoyance. What should I do I get around this? Do I start the initial script in a thread or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are speaking of PySide, I assume you program is a GUI one. In a GUI program all processing must occurs in a worker thread if you want to keep the UI responsive. So yes, the initial script must be start in a thread distinct from main thread (main one is *reserved* for UI)

Comment: I won't promise anything, but IMHO, it should work - I cannot imagine a valid reason for which it should break ... Just try and report if it does not work.